# Refreshing a server-generated template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-routing

One of my partials is a report—a static list of names and dates that's just for viewing and printing.

Since it's more efficient to render the report server-side, my API sends back HTML for the report request instead of JSON. The template URL in the report route is that API call:

```
.when('/report', {
    templateUrl: 'api/report',
});
```

The report shows up at the right URL, but when I go to another route and change the data, the report isn't reloaded. I tried setting the `no-cache` header in the API response, but it didn't have an effect.

Is there a best practice for forcing Angular to refresh certain templates?

Comment: Angular has an internal cache for templates, so it doesn't even have attempt to fetch from the server. You can remove an item from cache though. I believe you can use the `$templateCache` service and remove individual templates. You could remove it after that view has loaded, so ensure the next time it isn't cached

Comment: @Ian, that works! `$templateCache.remove('templateName');` in the controller removes the given template so that it reloads each time the route is visited. If you turn that into an answer, I'd be glad to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has an internal cache for templates, serviced by the `$templateCache` service. After a template is fetched from the server, its reference and content is cached inside Angular, and used instead of re-requesting it from the server.

The `$templateCache` service has two relevant methods for your situation - `.remove("templateUrl")` and `.removeAll()`. In the situation where you want to remove a specific template, you can obviously use the `.remove(templateUrl)` method.

This can be done in either the controller (which, when loaded, will have already loaded the template), or in a more general event, such as the global `$routeChangeSuccess` event. For example:

```
module.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, current, previous) {
        $templateCache.remove(current.$$route.templateUrl);
    });
}]);
```

While this will clear the specific entry in the Angular cache, you still need to make sure your server is setting the appropriate headers on the template's response so that when it is requested from the server, the browser doesn't cache it.

In a different scenario, if you never wanted any template to be cached within Angular, you could bind the global `$includeContentLoaded` and `$routeChangeStart` events and call `$templateCache.removeAll()` to make sure no templates are ever cached.